# The purpose of `serial:true` for concourse

Tags: concourse

I have a question about what `serial: true` does with respect to jobs. It seems a little redundant since `serial_groups` already seems to control the serial execution of multiple jobs. But at the same time inside of the `plan` there are constructs like `do` that run steps of a plan in a series.

The documentation says this:

> `serial: boolean`
>   Optional. Default false. If set to true, builds will queue up and execute one-by-one, rather than executing in parallel.

In in the "Concepts" section, concourse seems to define a "build" as

> An instance of execution of a job's plan is called a build

In that case, if you don't specify build steps inside of a `do`, will they run concurrently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`serial: true` means that a *specific job* will only run one build at a time, however putting multiple jobs in a single `serial_group` means that all of the jobs in that group will run serial in relation to one another.

For example, if I define job `job1` as `serial: true`, and quickly execute four builds of `job1`, then the first build will run, and builds 2, 3, and 4 will wait in `pending` state. When build 1 finishes, build 2 will kick off, and builds 3, and 4 will waiting in `pending` state, and so on.

If a define `job1`, `job2`, and `job3` in a `serial_group`, and I kick all of them off at the same time, then one of those jobs, lets say `job2`, will run, and the rest will wait in `pending` state. Then another job, lets say `job1` will run, and `job3` wil wait in `pending` state until `job2` finishes, and then `job3` will run.

Comment: So will the ordering of jobs inside of the same serial group depend on the order in which they were declared? Like if I wrote `job1` , `job2,` `job3` in that order and defined them within the same `serial_group`, will they always execute in that order?

Comment: I think so, I probably shouldn't have put them in a random order in the answer...

Comment: so just for clarification, if `serial:true` is not specified, the steps inside of a job will run concurrently?

Comment: No. `serial:true` does not have anything to do with the steps inside of a job. Steps can be run concurrently with `aggregate` blocks. https://concourse.ci/single-page.html#aggregate-step. `serial:true` means that each separate build of a specific job will only run one build at a time. So with `serial:true` you can `trigger` a job many times and it will not run more than one instance of that job at a time.

Comment: I've done some light testing on this matter and I haven't noticed a correlation between the names of jobs and the order which they are executed in a serial group.